# Make an DIV hold Position, when using Overflow command

Tags: css

I got 3 Divs, the first one is my Menupanel (Top). ~Around 30px Height, 100% Width.
The second is an Image. (Middle) ~Around 50% height, 85% width.
The third one is an Div with the Following settings.

```
.newsfeed {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
    width: 970px;
    min-height: 50px;
    left: 22px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    top: 75px;
}
```

Sure it looks perfect, and the Overflow works as a charm.
The picture does go behind the Topmenu, just what I want, and make it gone after it's over it.

But, the .Newsfeed is at the bottom ~Around bottom: 20px, and when I scroll, it goes up, behind my Topmenu and just keep scrolling up, I want to lock it before it reaches the Topmenu.

As said, the Topmenu (Menubar) is Top: 0; - Height: 30px;

How should I make my .Newsfeed DIV to stay when it reaches around Height: 60px; and hold that position, but so I still can scroll down, but it's locked at Height: 60px; from top: 75px; ?

I hope I was specific enough, if you miss anything, let me know and I'll answer asap.

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pcVQZ/5/)

As said, I want the #Newsfeed, to stop when it reaches 15px; close to #topmenu.

I really appreciate the answers available, and merry Christmas!

Comment: We need more.  HTML, rest of CSS, maybe a http://www.jsfiddle.com or two...feed us

Comment: I linked it in thread. http://jsfiddle.net/pcVQZ/